# Avoid Caching page on IONIC

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In this code I have two ways to tell to my app not caching all the views, said option A and B, which one do you recommend and why?

**Option A:**

```
.config(function ($ionicConfigProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.icon('ion-chevron-left');
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false).text('&emsp;');

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
})
```

**Option B:**

```
.run(function ($ionicPlatform, $ionicConfig) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
        // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
        // for form inputs)
        $ionicConfig.views.maxCache(0);

        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it is preferably to do all configuration settings in the config phase of the Ionic/Angular app, so in your example the Option A.

According to https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Dependency-Injection:

> The config phase is where you can set up any providers as necessary.
>   This is also where directives, controllers, filters, and the like get
>   set up.
>
> The run phase is where Angular actually compiles your DOM and starts
>   up your app.

However [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/provider/$ionicConfigProvider/) mention both the two ways:

> These configs can be changed using the $ionicConfigProvider during the
>   configuration phase of your app. *Additionally*, $ionicConfig can also
>   set and get config values during the run phase and within the app
>   itself.

The adverb *additionally* implies that the second option is residual.